# Segments/Processes running on same UDP socket

Tags: udp, socket

Suppose a process in Host C has a UDP socket with port number 12345. Suppose both Host A and Host B each sends a UDP segment to Host C with destination port number 12345. Will both of 
these segments be directed to the same socket at Host C? Why?

*I would think yes they would be since it doesnt matter that their two different segments as long as they're running on the same port of 12345 .*

Is this true? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct; because that's how listening sockets work.

Comment: It's how *UDP* listening sockets work. (Because UDP is connectionless, both datagrams are being sent to the same endpoint.)